# Function for Return Dictionary in swift 5

Tags: dictionary, swift5, nsmutabledictionary

I'm working on the client Project. I've seen a function that helps to append two Parameter in a single object like this

```
{
 "GroupType": "string",
 "Language": "string",
 "SecondaryParameter": {
   "LocalTags": [
     {
       "Key": "string",
       "Value": "string"
     },
    {
       "Key": "string",
       "Value": "string"
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

The Function which is used to make parameters returns in **NSMutableDictionary**

```
 private func setBodyParams(request: Any) -> NSMutableDictionary{
        //Initialize a NSMutableDictionary
        let dataDic = NSMutableDictionary()
        //Now
        let requestMirror = Mirror(reflecting: request)
        for child in requestMirror.children{
            if child.value is Array<Any>{
                dataDic.setObject(child.value, forKey: child.label! as NSCopying)
            }else{
                dataDic.setValue(child.value, forKey: child.label!)
            }
        }
        return dataDic
    }
```

it returns the parameter in **NSMutableDictionary*. now I have to remove this **NSMutableDictionary** Function and Create another function that returns **Dictionary** in an expected way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
private func setBodyParams(request: Any) -> [String : Any] {
        var dataDic: [String : Any] = [:]
        let requestMirror = Mirror(reflecting: request)
        for child in requestMirror.children {
            if child.value is Array<Any> {
                dataDic[child.label ?? ""] = child.value
            } else {
                dataDic[child.label ?? ""] = child.value
            }
        }
        return dataDic
    }
```

Comment: Why the `if child.value is Array<Any>` if the statements in the `if` and `else` clauses are the same?

Comment: @Willeke we set a Request type Any. but some data come from an Array of in that case if-else statement is executed.

Comment: But why? What is the difference between the first and second `dataDic[child.label ?? ""] = child.value`?